# Different session_id() on two pages on same domain

Tags: php, session, cookies

For some strange reason I get different session ids on two pages.

Let me illustrate the problem:

I have a webshop where a user can go to a checkout page, click the order button. This will open a payment link to a payment provider I use, this provider checks a script on my domain which is called exchange.php

If the status is 100 (success) the script redirects to another page on my domain called upload.php (rewritten to mysite.nl/voltooien with some parameters, full example: https://www.mysite.nl/voltooien?orderId=1697612595X0e3ce&orderStatusId=100&paymentSessionId=1697612595

For some reason on this upload.php page my user session ($_SESSION['user']) is gone, the user is logged out, but when I keep another tab open on a different page, for example the account page and refresh this page after completing an order, I stay logged in. The user session is active.

If I then go back to upload.php en refresh it's still gone. So I tried echoeing the session ids like this: `echo session_id();` in the header file which is included on both pages. And both show a different session id.

On upload.php: 0320c6c27e2d3b8138bde40dcca61443 and on account.php : bd1b6d9e4d21f19a87d5b13343eb99c4

Shouldn't they be the same? They are both on the same domain, nowhere do I unset the user session or destroy the entire session.

What can be causing this? I went overkill with `session_start();` to make sure this was not the issue and added it to all files that are included at the top but still have the same issue.

The code at the top of upload.php:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php";
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/phpMailer/Exception.php";
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
$productmenu = 'false';
$page = 'order_done';
$title = 'Bedankt voor je bestelling!';
if ($_GET['orderStatusId'] == '100') {
    unset($_SESSION['producten']);
    unset($_SESSION['kortingscode']);
}
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/header.php';
// Clear empty session values
unset($_SESSION['producten']['']);
echo session_id();
?>
```

The code at the top of my header.php which includes a connection file with `session_start();` , I also tried adding it to the top of this file with no success. This file is included first at the top of my account page:

```
<?PHP
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/connection.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/connection_studio.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/connection_extern.php';
$conn = new Connection;
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/catalog/lastorder.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/createdesignfavarray.php';
```

And in my exchange.php file which also has session_start(); at the top, the only thing I do with sessions is unsetting a different product session and coupon session like this:

```
// Empty product session
unset($_SESSION['producten']);
unset($_SESSION['kortingscode']);
```

I don't do anything with the user session here.

No clue what is causing this. Can it be something is bugged or something in my hosting needs to be changed?

Comment: Check the SameSite attribute of your session cookie. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Comment: It seems as if the browser which is requesting upload.php is not passing over the cookie stored for your site along with the request, meaning the server just generates a new session. Most likely related to security settings of the cookie storing the session ID. If you can't solve it, one way to overcome this would be to send the session ID as a parameter in the URL and then when you retrieve it, you could perform some checks to prevent malicious actors from spoofing it.